# <h:commandButton> is not refreshing page after actioned

Tags: jsf, richfaces

hi we are using  along with a4j tag.

here we are retrieving data from database after a click of button. even though the data is available in server, it will not display over view. After manual refresh of web page will lead to data diplay.

here is code snippet
    
    
       .... some code here

```
  <rich:tab id="menu5" label="Recall">
  <ui:include src="/pages/mctrans/reCallMcifTrans.xhtml" />  
  </rich:tab>
```

reCallMcifTrans.xhtml contains below code

```
<h:commandButton type="button" id="reCallbutton1" value="   Search   "
    styleClass="commandExButton">
    <a4j:support event="onclick" id="ajsf12"
        oncomplete="javascript:alert('Search   Completed');javascript:document.body.style.cursor='default';"
        action="#{mcifRecallTransBean.reCallSearch}" reRender="reCallgrid1" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: What is the scope of your bean? Is there get parameters in url?

Comment: Bean scope is session level. passing search parameters

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're working with RichFaces 3.3. So, you don't need a `<h:commandButton` with `<a4j:support>` because you can use [`<a4j:commandButton>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_commandButton.html) that already does this. You can refactor your code to this:

```
<a4j:commandButton type="button" id="reCallbutton1" value="Search"
    styleClass="commandExButton"
    action="#{mcifRecallTransBean.reCallSearch}"
    reRender="reCallgrid1"
    oncomplete="javascript:alert('Search   Completed');javascript:document.body.style.cursor='default';" />
```

Make sure your `reCallgrid1` component is available in the same `<h:form>` of the `<a4j:commandButton>`.

Since you also want to add a *Wait while searching the data* behavior when the button is clicked, you can use [`<a4j:status>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_status.html) along with the `<a4j:commandButton>` as shown in the [`<a4j:status>` demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/status.jsf;jsessionid=CC5043704D1272996EE0305CCFAFDD0D?c=status&tab=usage). Here's a basic example:

```
<a4j:commandButton type="button" id="reCallbutton1" value="Search"
    styleClass="commandExButton"
    action="#{mcifRecallTransBean.reCallSearch}"
    reRender="reCallgrid1" />
<!-- Note that there's no oncomplete in this case -->
<a4j:status for="reCallbutton1">
    <f:facet name="start">
        <h:graphicImage  value="/res/images/wait.gif"/>
    </f:facet>
</a4j:status>
```

At last but not least, you should switch your managed bean to request scope and use RichFaces powerful [`<a4j:keepAlive>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_keepAlive.html) in order to simulate JSF 2 [`@ViewScoped`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html). You can even use it in form of annotation on your managed bean (no additional configuration):

```
@KeepAlive
public class McifRecallTransBean {
    //managed bean code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using request parameters inside the bean, you need to pass them again with your action :

```
<h:commandButton type="button" id="reCallbutton1" value="Search" styleClass="commandExButton">
    <a4j:support event="onclick" id="ajsf12" oncomplete="javascript:alert('Search  Completed');javascript:document.body.style.cursor='default';" action="#{mcifRecallTransBean.reCallSearch}" reRender="reCallgrid1" />
    <f:param name="param1" value="#{param['param1']}" />
    <f:param name="param2" value="#{param['param2']}" />
</h:commandButton>
```